# Best way of learning dealing with DEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I'm from a cognitive science/computer science background. As I'm currently dealing with neuroscience a lot, I want to get better at dealing with DEs. My primary goal is to learn the tools required for solving equations/IVPs. In parallel I'm reading the book written by S. H. Strogatz to get a better intuition about dynamical systems.

I'm guessing that what I'm looking for is something like a book that comes with many exercises complete with solutions (I tend to be faster when I can learn by doing), so I'd be happy if you could recommend me something in this direction. However, if you've other suggestions (e.g. online resources), I'm eager to hear about them too.

PS: I 'should' have some basic understanding calculus but one problem is that it's been a very long time since I used it the last time.

Comment: For the basics of DE's, there's Stewart's Calculus book. For more advanced stuff with Volterra-Lotka, Laplace Transformations and Linear Algebra, refer to answers ahead.